# Symfony 2 file upload set default file

Tags: php, symfony

I have a form in my Symfony2 app where I ask a user to upload a file. This field is not required. Currently I process the user`s file with the following command:

```
$file = $form['attachement']->getData();
```

My question is how can I set a default file in case $file returns NULL, i.e. the user does not want to upload any file?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to create a valid object from your default file.
To do that, use the [Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.html).

Usage: `$file = new File('path/of/your/default/file');`

Then, you have to update your form before the data binding is done.
For that, you have two solutions :

1- Use a `FormEvent` to manually set the file if the field is null. (e.g. `PRE_SUBMIT` and `POST_SUBMIT`)

2- Use a prePersist/preUpdate hook in your entity. (Doesn't involves to move your logic, the unmapped property 'attachment' should already exists in your entity)

For the option 1, see the [Dynamic form modification](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#adding-an-event-listener-to-a-form-class) chapter of the cookbook and look for the appropriated event (the documentation will give the informations to choose it).

For the 2, see the [Events](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html) chapterof Doctrine documentation.
Something like the following should do the job :

```
/**
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class YourEntity {
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function manageFile()
    {
        if ($this->attachment === null) {
            $file = new File('path/of/your/default/file');
            $this->setAttachment($file);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it's sufficient for you.

Comment: Thank You. Actually `$file = new File('path/of/your/default/file');` was enough to do all the stuff))

Answer (score 0):

I guess, doctrine [`Lifecycle Events`](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events) should help you. Use `prePersist` or `preUpdate` event to check is `$this->file === null`, and set default value.

Comment: Currently I check if the file!=null in my controller. The problem is that I want to set a default file in else statement but I can`t find a function for that. If I use setFile("file/path") I get Call to a member function setFile() on null.

Comment: @Jack, you can move this logic from controller to entity. It allows you to set default value in time, when entity created. Is that what you want?

Comment: Actually I would like to leave it in a controller as it is now. But if there is no way for that, I would move it to entity. I`ve read the docs about Lifecycle callbacks but did not find any info on how to set a default file either((.Maybe somebody could point on it?